# Creating an exclusion in Python

Tags: python, loops

I'm writing a program that should add all positive values that a user enters, and the program should loop until he/she enter a negative number. The program loops smoothly but it includes the negative number in the sum. Any help is appreciated!

```
def main ():    
    X=0    
    Y=0

    print("I can add the sum of all positive numbers")
    X = int (input ("Please enter a positve number between 0 and infinity: ")) 

   if X > 0:
        while Y >= 0: 
            print("I can add the sum of all positive numbers")
            Y = int(input("Please enter a positive number between 0 and infinity: ")) 
            X = X + Y
       print("The sum of the numbers you entered is: ", X)  

   else:
        print("Sorry I can only add positive numbers")

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the addition `X = X + Y` before you input the number (but inside the `while`). You initialized both variables so the "extra" addition before entering a number is just `X = 0 + 0` and has no negative effect.

Otherwise it will execute the addition one more time (even if you entered a negative number) before the while loop exits. The condition of the while loop is only tested when first trying to enter it and each time the code inside it is finished and the program checks if it should perform another "loop".